# Google Maps menu in Russian

Tags: google-maps, localization

I can't change Google Maps menu to English. English is my language of choice throughout Google, but in Google Maps the menu is in Russian. How can I change it to English?

Comment: What URL are you using? If the domain ends in `.ru` I'd expect the interface to be in Russian.

Answer (score 0):

To change the language in the menu of the Google maps,Please follow the below steps.

(i) Click on the  wheel icon on the bottom of the page in the right side.

(ii) Choose the search history and then click on languages.

(iii)Now check the language you need and then save it.

Now you can see the menu in the Google maps are listed to your desired language.

Answer (score -1):

If am I not wrong understanding your question you are looking at this:
Search in another language

You can choose to search country-specific versions of Google from Toolbar's search box:

Click Toolbar's wrench wrench icon.
On the General tab, select a country domain from the 'Use Google site' drop-down menu.
Click Save.
Use localized versions of Toolbar

Toolbar is available in a whopping 40 languages. To use a different language version, see the instructions below:

Click Toolbar's wrench wrench icon.
On the General tab, select a language from the 'Toolbar language' drop-down menu.
Click Save.